# MAMP Apache on MacOS Monterey won't start, it says I need to codesign each module

Tags: apache, mamp, code-signing, macos-monterey

I have MAMP installed on MacOS Monterey, and while it worked fine for several weeks, it is now unable to start its Apache server.

The initial error was:

```
AH06665: No code signing authority for module at /Applications/MAMP/Library/modules/mod_access_compat.so specified in LoadModule directive.
httpd: Syntax error on line 72 of /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf: Code signing absent - not loading module at: /Applications/MAMP/Library/modules/mod_access_compat.so
```

(`mod_access_compat.so` is the first in a long list of LoadModules.)

I codesigned that module, and got another error: the same error, just for the next LoadModule in the list (`actions_module modules/mod_actions.so`).

Can anyone help me find out why MAMP suddenly started producing this error? Am I going to have to codesign all seventy remaining LoadModules just to use MAMP?

This is with PHP 7.4. MAMP's error message: "Apache couldn't be started. Please check your MAMP installation and configuration."

Comment: I'm getting this error again in March 2023.